# Do I need to take additional log det Jacobians for every PDF that uses the reparameterization trick?

Tags: variational-inference

Consider the - ELBO objective with reparameterization which is also used in VAE's:$$
\mathcal L_{\theta,\phi}(x)=\log p_\theta(X|Z)+\log p_\theta(Z) +\log q_\phi(Z)
$$

The reparameterization trick makes use of $g(\epsilon, \phi)$ such that $\epsilon$ is not dependent of $\phi$ so we can push the gradients to optimize the ELBO (single Monte Carlo sample).

Now due to transformation of variables, I need to take $$
\log q_\phi(Z)=\log p(\epsilon) +\log\left|\det \frac{\partial Z}{\partial \epsilon} \right|
$$

---

**My question is, do I need to add another log det jacobian for the term $\log p_\theta(Z)$?**

$P_\theta(Z)$ is the prior for $Z$. I am sampling $Z$ from $g(\epsilon,\phi)$ to make the ELBO backpropagable. However, in the usual algorithms for VAE (like in Kingma's), there is no log det Jacobian for $P_\theta(Z)$
[image: algo]

Also, if I take the log det Jacobian for $p_\theta(Z)$, the log det Jacobians would cancel as in the ELBO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the notation and context is taken from the [An Introduction to
Variational Autoencoders](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.02691). Following the same notation,

You don't need another log det of jacobian term for $p_{\theta}(Z)$ because $p_{\theta}(Z)$ is a prior over $Z$ with no learnable parameters. Think of it as $p(Z_0)$. It is assumed to be a Gaussian distribution in case of above paper. Throughout the learning process of VAE, this prior distribution doesn't change.

However, In $q_{\phi}(Z|X)$, $Z$ is sampled through $\epsilon$ and smooth invertible transformation $g(x, \epsilon, \phi)$. Hence, a reparametrization with respect to $\epsilon$ was necessary to compute $\nabla_{\phi}(q_{\phi}(Z|X))$.

Ideally in standard Bayes methods, We use this sample along with prior $p(Z_0)$ above to update posterior.(But not in the case of VAE)

Comment: I've assumed that this must be the only possible reason but you verified it, thank you!